# Concatenate two dataframes in Spark 1.5

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes in Scala, (initially as lists) and I want to append them. So for instance, if I had:
`val df1 = List(1, 2, 3)`
and 
`val df2 = List(4, 5, 6)`

I want to end up having a dataframe with two rows

---

### 1 2 3

### 4 5 6

I found somewhere that if I transformed this lists into actual dataframes and do something like `val df = df1.union(df2)` I would get what I need, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in Spark 1.5

Comment: You can wirte somthing like `df1.zip(df2).flatMap(pair => List(pair._1, pair._2))`. But better use union http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#union(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) it must work.

Comment: are you asking how to turn a list to a dataframe or how to do a union of two dataframes?

Comment: A union of two dataframes

Answer (score 0):

In your example, df1 and df2 are not dataframes but rather lists. Assuming they are indeed dataframes then you can do:

```
val df3 = df1.unionAll(df2)
```